# Build Listview from Code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I have a large table that can have many null, empty or false columns. I only want to show the columns that are worth showing. 
Here is a sample of the query and how I am trying to build up the `listview`:

```
var query = (from q in db.tblIncidents
            where q.Id == searchQuery
            select  new
                {
                    q.victim,
                    q.reportedByVictimPostCode
                }).ToList();
lst_Results.DataSource = query;
lst_Results.DataBind();

foreach (var colitem in query)
{
    if (!colitem.victim == false)
    {
         ** Help required here please **           
        lst_Results.Items.Add(new ListViewDataItem(0,1));
    }
}
```

I did start off building my list view on the aspx page, but realised that the result would be lots of empty fields and a waste of time for the user seeing nothing if the user hadn't entered any thing.

What I want to do is achieve this but in the code behind by querying if there is a result to display.

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
        <td>Incident Id:</td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lbl_CustomerId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Id") %>' />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Reported by the Victim:</td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lbl_victim" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("victim") %>' />
        </td>
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Would I use something like so?

```
lst_Results.InsertItem.DataItem(colitem.victim);
```

Which I get the error `method delegate or event expected`?

Does it know to insert into the `listItem` template?

I have a layout template with the `itemPlaceholder`. The `listview` works ok just want to target it from code behind.

Comment: Would you be interested in using another control?  Because you could use a GridView and auto-generate the columns based on the dataset that you bind to it.

Comment: I am looking at other controls to achieve this.